# Querying special character from SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, unicode

When I saved special characters in a column of type `nvarchar`, I did not use the prefix `'N'`, so the characters got saved as `??`.

Is there any way to retrieve the original special characters from these question marks?

Any kind of suggestion will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately no, if you have written special characters on a `VARCHAR` and not `NVARCHAR` (by omitting the `N`), their binary storage representation changed and there is no way to retrieve the original. Please note that this only applies when writting explicit strings as they need the `N` before the literal, if it's assigned throughout an update (for example) with a `NVARCHAR` column, the values will still retain their correct values.

---

You can see differences on the following examples. Here we write unicode chinese characters to an `NCHAR` and display both `NCHAR` and `CHAR` versions (their behaviour is similar to `NVARCHAR` and `VARCHAR` respectively, for this matter):

```
DECLARE @char NCHAR(1) = N'人'

SELECT
    NChar = @char,
    Char = CONVERT(CHAR(1), @char)
```

Result:

```
NChar   Char
人       ?
```

Here you can see the data loss, we show the binary representation of both the `NCHAR` and the `CHAR` with 2 different unicode characters. Please note that both are different characters but *they are stored as the same* on `VARCHAR` / `CHAR` data types.

```
DECLARE @char NCHAR(1) = N'人'
DECLARE @char2 NCHAR(1) = N'物'

SELECT
    NChar = @char,
    Char = CONVERT(CHAR(1), @char),
    NChar2 = @char2,
    Char2 = CONVERT(CHAR(1), @char2)

SELECT
    BinaryNChar = CONVERT(VARBINARY, @char),
    BinaryChar = CONVERT(VARBINARY, CONVERT(CHAR(1), @char)),
    BinaryNChar2 = CONVERT(VARBINARY, @char2),
    BinaryChar2 = CONVERT(VARBINARY, CONVERT(CHAR(1), @char2))
```

Results:

```
NChar   Char    NChar2  Char2
人       ?       物       ?

BinaryNChar BinaryChar  BinaryNChar2    BinaryChar2
0xBA4E      0x3F        0x6972          0x3F
```

`NVARCHAR` holds 2 bytes for each character while `VARCHAR` just 1. Considering this, you can't revert the conversion back from `VARCHAR` to `NVARCHAR` for special characters.

Comment: But what happens if you store a double-byte character (Unicode) of 1 character length in a `char(2)` field? Couldn't that be retrievable?

Comment: Conversions are made on a character basis. Even if you have enough bytes on your data type to store the information, converting a unicode character (that requires 2 bytes per character) to a `CHAR(n)` (that requires just 1 per character) will only use it's 1-byte representation, leaving the rest of the bytes as blank.

Comment: @hot2use, each character is converted regardless of the number of bytes used to represent the character. Non-ASCII characters are mapped according to the target collation code page. When the character doesn't exist in the code page, it is either mapped to a similar character or to '?' when no similar character exists. The data cannot be converted back to the original source character in these cases.

Comment: @DanGuzman yes, just found out the same during testing. Once you have an `?` it's already broken.